# How can I strengthen my submitted graduate application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, germany, international-students

I am applying for a master degree in Germany. I have submitted my application but wish to strengthen it as I want to be accepted. What can I do to enhance my application? Can I contact any of the professors or maybe the student advisor? Will it look artificial? If so, what must I say? (I am coming from abroad otherwise I would have visited the university).

Besides, can I email a professor and communicate to him that I am applying for graduate study, and I was intrigued by his research and wish, if accepted, to work with him? Is it too early to do so before even getting accepted?

I apologize if my questions seem trivial, but this is my first graduate application, and I hope to do all that it is in my power to get accepted.

Comment: I don't know Germany, so I won't answer, but in general, the time to "boost" your application is before submission.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143833/do-german-professors-in-a-master-s-program-respond-to-students-who-email-them-in/

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of efficiency and fairness, candidate selection is a purely administrative process, based on submitted paperwork only, and handled by academic staff that adhere to strict rules and work ethics. You should not disturb them, nor should you hope for any good effect of doing so.

If you want to enhance your chances, then apply in parallel to other universities or/and other master courses. Submit paperwork that excels in contents and layout.

Comment: This is more or less true lots of places, not just Germany. Not universal, I'd guess but widespread. In your written materials and any letters of recommendation, make your case for probable success.